# Can I make 4 new columns aggregating 4 previous ones?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set like this:

```
data = ({'A': ['John', 'Dan', 'Tom', 'Mary'], 'B': [1, 3, 4, 5], 'C': ['Tom', 'Mary', 'Dan', 'Mike'], 'D': [3, 4, 6, 12]})
```

Where Dan in A has the corresponding number 3 in B, and where Dan in C has the corresponding number 6 in D.

I would like to create 2 new columns, one with the name Dan and the other with 9 (3+6).

Desired Output

```
data = ({'A': ['John', 'Dan', 'Tom', 'Mary'], 'B': [1, 3, 4, 5], 'C': ['Tom', 'Mary', 'Dan', 'Mike'], 'D': [3, 4, 6, 12], 'E': ['Dan', 'Tom', 'Mary'], 'F': [9, 7, 9], 'G': ['John', 'Mike'], 'H': [1, 12]})
```

For names, John and Mike 2 different columns with their values unchanged.

I have tried using some for loops and .loc, but I am not anywhere close.

Thanks!

Comment: Your desired output is not very clear. Can you provide an example of your output DataFrame just like you have provided your input?

Comment: Column A has Dan on Row 2 and that's Row 3 for column C. So, when adding new columns where should the value for Dan be updated - 2/3?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide detailed information about your problem, a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and what you did try before posting. Some examples of inputs and expected outputs are always useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = data[['A','B']]
_df = data[['C','D']]
_df.columns = ['A','B']
df = pd.concat([df,_df]).groupby(['A'],as_index=False)['B'].sum().reset_index()
df.columns = ['E','F']
data = data.merge(df,how='left',left_on=['A'],right_on=['E'])
```

Although you can join on column C too, that's something you have choose. Or alternatively if you want just columns E & F, then skip the last line!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'A': ['John', 'Dan', 'Tom', 'Mary'], 'B': [1, 3, 4, 5], 'C': ['Tom', 'Mary', 'Dan', 'Mike'], 'D': [3, 4, 6, 12]}

df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df=df.rename(columns={"C": "A", "D": "B"})
df=df.stack().reset_index(0, drop=True).rename_axis("index").reset_index()
df=df.pivot(index=df.index//2, columns="index")
df.columns=map(lambda x: x[1], df.columns)
df=df.groupby("A", as_index=False).sum()
```

Outputs:

```py
>>> df

      A   B
0   Dan   9
1  John   1
2  Mary   9
3  Mike  12
4   Tom   7
```

Comment: On this line:

df=df.pivot(index=df.index//2, columns="index")

I get

KeyError: "None of ['index'] are in the columns" On the